# Join all lines of stream

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, zsh

How can I join all the lines?

Desired output:

```
$ echo 'one\ntwo' | tr '\n' ''
onetwo
```

Actual output:

```
tr: empty string2
```

I have also tried `paste -sd '' -` but get

```
paste: no delimiters specified
```

also `sed`

```
$ echo 'one\ntwo' | sed 's/\n//'
one
two
```

Comment: `echo 'one\ntwo'` produces a **single** line consisting of the string _one\ntwo_, as you cas easily verify by doing a `echo 'one\ntwo'|wc`. Furthermore your `tr` command produces the error message _tr: when not truncating set1, string2 must be non-empty_ for me (I'm using `tr` from GNU coreutils version 8.26). May I suggest that you provide an example which matches your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` requires that the second argument have at least one character, so it knows what to translate the characters in the first argument to. If there are less characters in the replacement string than in the match string, the last character of the replacement is used for all the rest. But if the replacement is empty, there's nothing to repeat for the rest.

If you want to delete characters, use `tr -d`.

```
echo $'one\ntwo' | tr -d '\n'
```

Note also that you have to use `$'...'` to get bash to treat `\n` as a newline. Otherwise it's the literal string `\n`.

Comment: I just tried it without `$` and it didn't work. Are you sure you used `echo`? If you use `printf 'one\ntwo'` you'll get newlines because printf translates escape sequences itself.

Comment: @theonlygusti Not in bash no. But I bet you are using zsh (edit: well, I see you even added the tag 'zsh', so no need for bet. But why are you also tagging 'bash' then? Those are different shells)

Comment: Don't tag your question with both `bash` and `zsh`. Use the tag of the shell you're actually using.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for

```
paste -sd '\0' -
```

`paste` interprets `\0` as the empty string, not the NUL byte.

```
$ printf '%s\n' one two | paste -sd '\0' - | od -t x1 -t a
0000000  6f  6e  65  74  77  6f  0a
          o   n   e   t   w   o  nl
0000007
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found

```
$ echo 'one\ntwo' | perl -p -e 's/\n//'
onetwo
```

there's not even a trailing newline